# Poisson distribution for rare event

Tags: probability-distributions

I was taught in school that Poisson distribution is usually used to model rare events. And I understand the Poisson process is such that the probability of an event in one interval is independent of another interval and the probability depends on the length of the interval. However, I don't understand why an event has to be a rare one. Anyone knows? 
Thanks!  =)

Comment: You can make thé parameter take values small enough to fit any average frequency.

Comment: L'espérance de ton processus est intensité x t. Donc en choisissant l'intensité tu peux obtenir une frequence rare.

Comment: L'intensité c'est le nombre moyen de réalisations par unité de temps!

Comment: Pas de souci. Je te fais une petite synthèse dans une réponse ;)

Comment: pour des questions de modélisation aléatoire, [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) est un bon endroit ;)

Comment: un petit up ne ferait pas de mal :)

Comment: tu dois pouvoir accepter ma réponse normalement, non ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas ;) à la prochaine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Poisson process $X\sim P(\lambda)$:

- the increments are independant with the same distribution
- the average increment of the process in an interval of size $\Delta t$ is $E[X_{t_0+\Delta t} - X_{t_0}] = \lambda\Delta t$, so the empirical average number of realizations on the whole time of the empirical data is a good way to choose the parameter of the Poisson process
- when a certain interval is likely to be contain a big increment, the modelization via a Poisson process (or any other Levy process) is not a good idea...